# SSH-Key does not get unlocked even with ssh-add

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm very confused. Every manual I read the last 15 minutes tells me this should work but it does not:

```
$ ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-syXn9Tk09V9P/agent.16332; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=16333; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 16333;
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 16362
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
$ ssh-add .ssh/user\@server.de.key
Enter passphrase for .ssh/user@server.de.key: 
Identity added: .ssh/user@server.de.key (.ssh/user@server.de.key)
$ ssh-add -l
1023 SHA256:TQ6nDwMeeP9tHf43lAG0mC5cbIPx5h7RYxMUcYKJHPI .ssh/user@server.de.key (RSA)
$ ssh server.de
Enter passphrase for key '/home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key':
```

In the ssh config there is an entry for server.de with identity user and the provided ssh key.

The verbose output:

```
$ ssh -vvv server.de
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/iras/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/iras/.ssh/config line 127: Applying options for apache4
debug1: /home/iras/.ssh/config line 177: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "10.0.0.42" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.42 [10.0.0.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug1: identity file /home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key-cert type -1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.0.42:22 as 'user'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/iras/.ssh/known_hosts"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/iras/.ssh/known_hosts:69                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.0.42                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug3: send packet: type 20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
debug3: receive packet: type 20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa                                                                                                               
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug2: languages ctos:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
debug2: languages stoc:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
debug2: first_kex_follows 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
debug2: reserved 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KAU//7qfeZspCpZwJWB7tZdYqQkGwUHVMV+830TdTwE
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/iras/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/iras/.ssh/known_hosts:69
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.0.42
debug1: Host '10.0.0.42' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/iras/.ssh/known_hosts:69
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key
Enter passphrase for key '/home/iras/.ssh/user@server.de.key':
```

Comment: What about the verbose log? `ssh -vvv server.de`. What does the `ssh-add -L` prints after the  key is added to the agent?

Comment: @Jakuje added the requested output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you have explicitly specified your key in the `~/.ssh/config` and you don't have stored additional (un-encrypted) public key. Therefore the client is trying the keys listed in the configuration file first and the agent-keys later (it can not match them, because the explicit key is encrypted).

If my theory is right, it should work for you, if you remove the line `IdentityFile ~.ssh/user@server.de.key` from your `~/.ssh/config`, or export the public key to the `.ssh/user@server.de.key.pub`

```
ssh-keygen -yf .ssh/user@server.de.key > .ssh/user@server.de.key.pub
```

Comment: great! thank you very much. The second solution I like more